# Well Ordering implies Induction Proof doubt

Tags: proof-explanation, induction, natural-numbers, well-orders

I’m trying to understand the proof for the fact that that the Principle of Well-Ordering implies the Principle of Mathematical Induction; that is, if S ⊂ N such that 1 ∈ S and n + 1 ∈ S whenever n ∈ S, then S = N.

[image: From proofwiki]

In the above proof, how did they conclude that $k$ is in the set $S$. Thanks

Comment: Strictly speaking you also need the existence of a predecessor for the proof to work.  A counter example is the set of polynomials with natural number coefficients, well ordered but basic induction doesn't apply.  Where they say "this minimal elemental of S' has the form k+1" you need induction to actually prove that.

Comment: You're justified in a _little_ bit of skepticism, because there's an implicit fact being used here: that if $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\neq 0$, then there's some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $m=k+1$. This is _true_ for the usual definition of $\mathbb{N}$, but it has to be proved and it's absolutely needed for this proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By construction, the smallest element of $S'$ has the form $k+1$ and so $k<k+1$ lies in $S$ as $\Bbb N_0 = S\cup S'$.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum element of $S^{'}$ is $k + 1$, by the set difference $k \in S$. The key is that the union of $S$ and $S^{'}$ is $\mathbb N$.